# An 8-bit representation of decimal Numbers in java

Tags: java, binary

I am currently struggling with an exercise that would convert a signed decimal number between -128 and +127 to its 8-bit binary representation in the two’s complement number system.

I am able to get a representation of the positive numbers, however when the code runs for the input to be a negative, it does the computation, but I am unable to get the right Binary repersentation. For example "57" in 8-bit repersentation would be "00111001" and -57 in the same repersentation would be "11000111"

I am pretty sure I have to do an if statement however I can not get it to work. Very lost

```
    System.out.println("Please enter a decimal to modify into it's binary.");
            decimalInput = stdIn.nextInt();

            if (decimalInput < 0){
                decimalInput= Math.abs(decimalInput); 

                if(i==0){
                    binary[i]=1;
                }else if (i==1){
                    binary[i] = 0;
                }
            }

            for ( i = binary.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
                remain = decimalInput % 2;
                binary[i]=remain;
                decimalInput = decimalInput / 2;
            }

            for (i =0; i <8; i++){
                System.out.print(binary[i]);
            }
```

Comment: You need an `else` to stop the second `for` loop from running in the negative case.

Comment: can't you just use more consistent spaces and linebreaks in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are again computing the binary of a number in the next for loop with decimalInput (post you take absolute value of decimal number and convert that number to binary). You are repeating the same for loop.

You could do something like:

```
int computeValue = decimalInput;
if (decimalInput < 0){
     computeValue= Math.abs(decimalInput); 
}

for (...){
     negRemain = computeValue% 2;
     ...
}
```

EDIT for 2s complement:
    if (decimalInput < 0) {
        handleNegativeNumbers(binary);
    }

```
private static void onesComplements(int[] binary) {
    for (int i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {// will perform one's complement
        if (binary[i] == 0) {
            binary[i] = 1;
        } else {
            binary[i] = 0;
        }
    }
}

private static void twosComplement(int[] binary) {
    int carry = 1;
    for (int i = binary.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {// will perform two's complement by adding one
        if (carry == 1) {
            if (binary[i] == 0) {
                binary[i] = 1;
                carry = 0;
                break;
            } else {
                binary[i] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

private static void handleNegativeNumbers(int[] binary) {
    onesComplements(binary);
    twosComplement(binary);
}
```

Comment: This does work. So thank you! however I am having some trouble with using this solution then taking what you have provided a step further with turning the "negative decimal number" into an actual binary number by flipping the bits and adding one to the most far right bit.

Comment: Am not sure what you mean. Is this your assignment? If not i would suggest you look at `Integer.toBinaryString` api

Comment: I will take a look at the api, thank you. Let me try to rephrase, for example, an 8-bit representation of the decimal 57 is "00111001", the representation of a negative decimal like -57 is "11000111".  I have tried using a nested if statement that will basically do "if this indexed number of the array is 1, change to 0." or vice versa

Comment: Would you like me to just post it in the comment section without any styling? Or as like an answer below? I'm sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: Modify your question. say edit there and paste the code after that.

Comment: Please, any further input is appreciated.

Comment: See edited answer. Method names are self explanatory.